# (Titanium Studio) display tableview with sorted data

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, titanium-mobile

I use titanium studio for build an ios app.
I have a webservice which send me :

data:[{"date":"2012-07-04" ...},{"date":"2012-06-04" ...},{"date":"2012-05-04" ...} ...]

I'd like sort data by date before add/display them with a tableview like this:

*--------------------------------------------*

row 1 :  2012-O7-04

*--------------------------------------------*

row 2 :  2012-O7-01

*--------------------------------------------*

row 3 :  2012-O4-04

*--------------------------------------------*

row 4 :  2012-O1-07

*--------------------------------------------*

row 5 :  2011-12-31 with 4 children

*--------------------------------------------*

and when i click on row 5 it'll display his children:

*---------------------------------*

child 1 :  2011-12-31

*---------------------------------*

child 2 :  2011-12-31

*---------------------------------*

child 3 :  2011-12-31

*---------------------------------*

child 4 :  2011-12-31

*---------------------------------*

How can I do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for sorting your array,

```
var feedArray = [
    {title: 'Feed 1', desc: 'Desc 1', date: '2012-04-10'},
    {title: 'Feed 2', desc: 'Desc 2', date: '2012-04-12'},
    {title: 'Feed 3', desc: 'Desc 3', date: '2012-03-18'} 
];

function findFeedByDate(d) {
    for(var i = 0; i < feedArray.length; i++) {
        if ( d == feedArray[i].date ) {
            return feedArray[i];
        }
    }
}

// Grab date from feed, push it to array, then use Array.sort() to sort array
var dateArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < feedArray.length; i++) {
    dateArray.push(feedArray[i].date);
}
dateArray = dateArray.sort();
Ti.API.info( dateArray );

var sortedFeedArray = [];
var date = null;

// for(var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) { // ASC Sorting
for(var i = dateArray.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) { // DESC Sorting   
    sortedFeedArray.push(
        findFeedByDate( dateArray[i] )
    );
}
Ti.API.info( sortedFeedArray );
```

For more detailed solutions please check this link: [Sort TableView Row by date in Titanium Studio](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135454/sort-tableview-row-by-date)